# Snippets for C++ in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

Does someone know of any port to VS2008 of the support for snippets for C++?

VS2005 had a nice enhancement pack:

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 IDE Enhancements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd7c6e48-e41b-48e3-881e-a0e6e97f9534&DisplayLang=en)

But the snippets for C++ feature is not supported in VS2008. I already tryed to use the SDK to reimplement it but gave up out of lack of time since are a huge number of Language details to know in Babel. I find hard to believe nowone has needed this and implemented it as snippets can be one of the most effective production accelerators when used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Whole Tomato's [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for years, and it has a very nice snippets system built into it.  It is very straightforward to define snippets using the visual assist UI, and it also has some great features that enhance intellisense and code navigation. It is $99 though, but well worth it in my opinion.